# vc ++ compatibility problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, sdk

I'm using  VS 6.0 and  VS2008. But the problem is VS2008 SDK is not compatible with VS(VC++)

6.0 SDK. To resolve this i have used  Windows® Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK Web Install.  If I
build the code in release mode its working but if did in debug mode then its giving an error 
like this

> WbemUuid.Lib(wbemcli_i.obj) : fatal error LNK1103: debugging information corrupt; recompile module
>   Error executing link.exe.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The last version of the Windows SDK that is compatible with VC6 is the Feb 2003 Edition - that predates the Win Server 2003 SP1 SDK by at least a year.

I'm not sure if it's downloadable any more except on MSDN (it is available there).

You may want to consider whether it's worthwhile to continue doing anything other than maybe maintenance of legacy code with VC6.

It turns out that you can still (as of 3 July 2011) order a CD/DVD version of the Feb 2003 SDK for "shipping and handling" from:

- http://mssdk.orderport.net/22221848/productpage.asp?title=Microsoft%20Platform%20SDK,%20February%202003%20Edition

Note that I haven't verified that this order page actually still works, I don't know if the offer extends globally, and I don't know how much is charged for shipping/handling.

(use [this link](http://mssdk.orderport.net/22221848/showall.asp) to see all the SDK discs available).

Answer (score 1):

I'm still using VC6 very often, it's not so bad.

To get rid of the link error, don't add `wbemuuid.lib` in your project setting.
If you miss any symbol, just define it.
If you really need any function from this dll, use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` instead.

For example, if you need `CLSID_WbemLocator` and `IID_IWbemLocator`, just define them by yourself:

```
GUID MY_CLSID_WbemLocator = {0x4590f811, 0x1d3a, 0x11d0, {0x89, 0x1f, 0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x4b, 0x2e, 0x24}};
GUID MY_IID_IWbemLocator = {0xdc12a687, 0x737f, 0x11cf, {0x88, 0x4d, 0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x4b, 0x2e, 0x24}};
```

And then use `MY_XXXX` in your code.